# how to create .htaccess file to recreate a frindly URL

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this URl :

> localhost/prefinal/profile.php?username=Admin

and want to make it :

> localhost/prefinal/profile/Admin

i use the .htaccess file and set the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /prefinal/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

The page works fine .. but the CSS is not working in it :

[not work css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASfiy.jpg)

Should be :

[work css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZTae.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: You need to add base href='' in the headers of your html..

Answer (score 1):

How Your HTML sours looks like (`link` tags to stylesheets)?
I guess You should add few lines **before** RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /prefinal/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: it's PHP not html 
this is my style sheet link:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css.css">